# Connect Orbeon Xform to External Exist DB

Tags: orbeon, xforms, exist-db

I am attempting to connect a new Orbeon XForm to an existing exist db. My code should submit an xml doc to be stored in that database.

```
<xf:submission id="save-to-file"
            method="get"
            action="http://server:8081/exist/rest//test/test/inventory_sample.xml" 
            replace="instance" instance="data-instance" includenamespaceprefixes="ai"/>
```

When attempting to submit my xml file, my log reveals an authentication error:

```
Apr 6, 2010 2:06:08 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthChallengeProcessor
 selectAuthScheme
INFO: basic authentication scheme selected
Apr 6, 2010 2:06:08 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector processW
WWAuthChallenge
INFO: No credentials available for BASIC 'exist'@kruddler.mitre.org:8081
```

How do I authenticate this connection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve BASIC authentication, you need to do one of the following:

include credentials in action:

```
<xforms:submission method="get" action="http://john:password@example.org/list" separator="&amp;"/>
```

Use the two extension attributes, xxforms:username and xxforms:password:

```
 <xforms:submission  method="get" action="http://example.org/list" separator="&amp;" xxforms:username="john" xxforms:password="password"/>
```